# Cumulative Days in Overlapping Date Ranges

Tags: date, crystal-reports, report, range

I use Crystal Reports 11.

What I'd like to do is get a count of the unique days a student was enrolled in one of our many programs.  If a student was enrolled in 3 programs in which the dates overlapped, I'd just want to count each day once and get a number.

Example using a student:

```
Algebra Jan 1 to Jan 10: 10 days
Science Jan 4 to Jan 11: 8 days
English Jan 9 to Jan 13: 4 days
```

I'd want the answer to be 13.

Comment: Will the date ranges always overlap?

Comment: No. the dates may overlap not always with thousands of patient, there is no telling.

Answer (score 0):

Good point.  If they always over lap then this will work

Create a formula that finds maximum end date and the minimum start date based on patient.  Then minus each formula.

i.e.: Maximum({xxx.enddate}, {xxx.patient}) - Minimum({xxx.startdate}, {xxx.patient})

If there are gaps between program dates, this won't work because it will include them.

Comment: There will likely be many gaps.  i was thinking i needed to create a loop to fill an array and then find the unique dates.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping the field by the patient name and Using

```
DistinctCount()
```

may be helpful.